# How was my answer deleted recently?

Tags: support, answers, deleted-posts

I've just entered English.SE (some 5 days ago). On the first day, I answered a question regarding the word "fantabulous". Now when I look into my profile, it indicates that I haven't posted anything yet and my rep. at **101**..?

So, Is that post completely deleted now?

Answer (score 2):

[The question itself](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94507/is-fantabulous-an-english-word/) was deleted by the community, and thus your answer was removed, as it makes little sense to have answers without the question.

The original text of your post, in case you want it:

> The word *fantabulous* exist. But, it is not indicated in many dictionaries (even my auto-spell check doesn't show such a word).
>
> I'm using [Word Web](http://wordweb.info/) - a pocket dictionary. It says - an ***informal*** : 'very good; of the highest quality'. After skimming through several sources, it seems that the word was originally blended from *fantastic* and *fabulous* in the 1950s.
>
> My other references which include American Oxford Dictionary and Chambers dictionary provide the same synonym - "Superb, Excellent, Marvelous, Wonderful", etc.

Comment: Nah, I don't require it. But, I was just curious - *"What happened to it?"*. Anyways, Thank you Waiwai :-)